# How can I delete specific duplicates of a Pandas Dataframe according to a rule? The duplicates don't look exactly the same necessarily

Tags: pandas, duplicates, similarity, difflib

Let's assume we hava a Dataframe looking like this:

| Index | FirstName | Surname | Adress | Source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Paul | Baggins | same | good |
| 2 | Paaul | Baggins | same | bad |
| 3 | Mary | Baggins | same | good |
| 4 | Mary | Baggins | same | bad |
| 5 | Lucy | Smith | other | bad |

We want to clean up the Dataframe.
First we filter people living at the same adress. We can be sure that adresses are unique for each household.
There we want to delete potential duplicates, because we used different data sources and unfortunately there might be some typing errors in the column "FirstName".

How can we delete the duplicates (in our case index rows 2 and 4)?

I found out that we could delete "exact" duplicates by using

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['FirstName','Surname', 'Adress'], keep='first')
```

This way Index 4 will be deleted. But this is not what I am looking for.

To delete index row 2 I want to compare the text of "FirstName" Index 1 and 2 and tried using the following function:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

similar(text_a, text_b)
```

Using
`similar('Paul', 'Paaul')"`
results in 0.888

But I don't see how to put all this together.

The "manipulated" Dataframe should look like this:

| Index | FirstName | Surname | Adress | Source | Similar_to_Index | Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Paul | Baggins | same | good | 2 | 0.8888 |
| 2 | Paaul | Baggins | same | bad | 1 | 0.8888 |
| 3 | Mary | Baggins | same | good | 4 | 1.0 |
| 4 | Mary | Baggins | same | bad | 3 | 1.0 |
| 5 | Lucy | Smith | other | bad | NaN | NaN |

Then index rows 2 and 4 should be deleted by the rule that the relevant ratio is >0.8 and the column "Source" is labeled "bad".
The problem is how to create the Column "Similar_to_Index" I guess.

The final result should be like this:

Cleaned Dataframe:

| Index | FirstName | Surname | Adress | Source | Similar_to_Index | Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Paul | Baggins | same | good | 2 | 0.8888 |
| 3 | Mary | Baggins | same | good | 4 | 1.0 |
| 5 | Lucy | Smith | other | bad | NaN | NaN |

Deleted_Entries_Dataframe:

| Index | FirstName | Surname | Adress | Source | Similar_to_Index | Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Paaul | Baggins | same | bad | 1 | 0.8888 |
| 4 | Mary | Baggins | same | bad | 3 | 1.0 |

Thank you very much for any suggestions and help.

Comment: Do you only want to compare on the first name? If not what is the rule?

Comment: Yes, only on the First_Name. The Rule would be to check if the address is the same. Unfortuantely there are other people living at this address. Thus next there would be a comparison of the Firstname of all people of that household and if two look very similar (let's say >80%), like Paul and Paaul (0.88) or Mary and Mary (1.0) I like to delete the one with the source "bad". Sorry for not making this clearer. I tried to correct the rule in the question.

Comment: then your question is too complex (out of the scope of stackoverflow, it should be one issue only, not asking someone to code you a full program). I am thus answering on the first part (how to obtain the best match above a threshold based on the first name)

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort and the feedback. I am an absolute beginner with programming, new to this platform and glad to learn how to handle future questions as well. Thus I will try my best to make shorter questions in the future. I tried to solve my original question with a lot of effort. I also try to implement your given code, but it is hard for me. I will take some more hours, because what is easy for you takes ages for me right now. But that's okay, because I want to learn that. I did not know, that such a huge code is necessary for that. Sorry about that. And thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to check all pairs of names, then select the top match:

```
from itertools import combinations
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

# compare all combinations of names
def compare(s):
    return [similar(a, b) for a, b in combinations(s, 2)]

# compute unique combinations, assign the reverse combinations (a->b ; b->a)
# find the best match
tmp = pd.Series(compare(df['FirstName']),
                index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([idx1, idx2])).unstack()
tmp = tmp.add(tmp.T, fill_value=0)

MAX = tmp.max(axis=1)
m = MAX > 0.8

out = df.assign(Similar_to_Index=tmp.idxmax(axis=1).where(m),
                Ratio=MAX.where(m)
                )
```

Output:

```
      FirstName  Surname Adress Source  Similar_to_Index     Ratio
Index                                                             
1          Paul  Baggins   same   good               2.0  0.888889
2         Paaul  Baggins   same    bad               1.0  0.888889
3          Mary  Baggins   same   good               4.0  1.000000
4          Mary  Baggins   same    bad               3.0  1.000000
5          Lucy    Smith  other    bad               NaN       NaN
```

Splitting the data in two:

```
dup = np.maximum(out.index, out['Similar_to_Index']).duplicated()

Cleaned_Dataframe = out[~dup]
#       FirstName  Surname Adress Source  Similar_to_Index     Ratio
# Index                                                             
# 1          Paul  Baggins   same   good               2.0  0.888889
# 3          Mary  Baggins   same   good               4.0  1.000000
# 5          Lucy    Smith  other    bad               NaN       NaN

Deleted_Entries_Dataframe =out[dup]
#       FirstName  Surname Adress Source  Similar_to_Index     Ratio
# Index                                                             
# 2         Paaul  Baggins   same    bad               1.0  0.888889
# 4          Mary  Baggins   same    bad               3.0  1.000000
```

*NB. if you sort the rows to have the "good" source on the top, then those will be kept preferentially as non-duplicate.*

Comment: That's awesome. Thank you very much! I understood what happens in the first part of the code by now. This works. For the second part I get the error "name 'idx1' is not defined". What do we need to enter there, please?

Comment: It took me a while to understand how to define idx1 and idx2. Here are my solutions. I don't know if that's what mozway meant, but it seems to work: idx1 = [a for a, b in combinations(df.index, 2)] and idx2 = [b for a, b in combinations(df.index, 2)]. Thanks again, mozway. I learned some very interesting new things.

Comment: @Poldi sorry, I had missed your message. See update